# 3 panels ontop 1 frame

Tags: java, swing

I'm having real trouble placing three different panels on top a frame as i need to have different layouts on each panel. I just cant seem to get it to work and i have been trying for 4 days in a row now. I cant find where i am going wrong in this code.

I'm i doing this the best way?  Any ideas or help will be greatly appreciated!!!!!

**MY code:**

```java
    public Mem() {
    super("3 panels on 1 frame");       

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    setSize(500, 500);      
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel p3 = new JPanel();

    //Adding three different panels with borderlayout
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());  

    //Panel 1 is the Player Panel with labels
    JLabel ply1 = new JLabel("Player 1");
    JLabel ply2 = new JLabel("Player 2");
    JLabel ply3 = new JLabel("Player 3");
    JLabel ply4 = new JLabel("Player 4");
    p1.add(ply1); p1.add(ply2); p1.add(ply3); p1.add(ply4);

    //Panel 2 is the game panel with playingcards on it. (Clickable buttons)
    JButton card1 = new JButton("Card");
    p2.add(card1); p2.add(card1); p2.add(card1); p2.add(card1); p2.add(card1); p2.add(card1); p2.add(card1);
    p2.add(card1); p2.add(card1); p2.add(card1); p2.add(card1); p2.add(card1); p2.add(card1); p2.add(card1);

    //Panel 3 is the lower panel with the buttons new game & close on it. 
    JButton newGame = new JButton("New Game");
    newGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            startGame();
        }
    });
    JButton endGame = new JButton("Close");
    endGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            closeGame();
        }
    });
    p3.add(newGame);  
    p3.add(endGame);


    frame.add(p1, BorderLayout.EAST);  
    frame.add(p2, BorderLayout.CENTER);  
    frame.add(p3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    setVisible(true);   
}
```

Comment: @user1501127 You haven't told us what is going wrong with it. What are you expecting it to do and what is it doing with the current code? Use `setLayout` to put layouts on your panels

Answer (score 5):

There's a few things:

**1)** You adding a swing component multiple times will not duplicate it - it will be removed and added in the new location.  So this:

```
JButton card1 = new JButton("Card");
p2.add(card1); p2.add(card1); p2.add(card1); p2.add(card1); p2.add(card1); p2.add(card1); p2.add(card1);
p2.add(card1); p2.add(card1); p2.add(card1); p2.add(card1); p2.add(card1); p2.add(card1); p2.add(card1);
```

is the same as this:

```
JButton card1 = new JButton("Card");
p2.add(card1);
```

**2)** It seems like your class extends `JFrame`.  If so, delete all those references to `JFrame frame = new JFrame();`.  By using the `frame` variable, you're creating a frame that you're adding panels to, but not displaying.  So everywhere you see `frame.` delete it.

Example:

```
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

becomes

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

**3)** I'm sure some of the questions you asked previously had acceptable answers or you came up with an acceptable answer yourself.  You can reward those people for helping or you could provide the answer you found and accept that.  Then more people will spend time providing you with a good answer.  It's better for you, it's better for us, it's better for the random guy with the same question as you.

Comment: +1: The line `setLayout(new BorderLayout());` can be removed completely as this is the default layout for `JFrame`. :)

Answer (score 4):

You appear to be attaching your panels to a `JFrame` that never gets shown in your `Mem` frame constructor. You could remove or comment the line:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```

and use:

```
add(p1, BorderLayout.EAST);
add(p2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(p3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

You will then be able to see how components are arranged in your panels for any layout that you apply:

```
p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
// etc.
```

Comment: +1 for a good answer to the question.  I only posted my own answer because there were a few other little things and it didn't sink in what you were saying until I tried fixing the OP's problem.

Comment: `add(p1, BorderLayout.EAST);
..
add(p3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);`  Also consider using `add(p1, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
..
add(p3, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);`  which adapt better to different text orientations.